# sphinx-doc search engine plugins

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, python-sphinx, algolia

I am using sphinx-doc to build with over 344MB of source files. The inbuilt javascript search engine is very slow. I guess it is not intended to index and search large documentation.

Is there a search engine plugin for sphinx-doc. Is it possible to use another search engine like Elastic search or Algolia search?

Answer (score 1):

If your documentation is public you could try Algolia's DocSearch: https://community.algolia.com/docsearch/

Comment: No, my doc is private. I added HTTP auth to my site. Is there a work around?

Comment: DocSearch is open source so you could use it on your own